Salesforce Apex - POST multipart/form-data Content-Type + TEXT
This is the second case that I open regarding this topic to ask more specific questions (the first Using blob variables in apex code)
In the first one they already indicated to me a first solution based on this reference (https://enreeco.blogspot.com/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html)
Context: I receive from an external service a pdf stored in a blob variable. Once I receive the file (I had always received it in base64, but now I have to receive it in a blob because it is the only thing that the provider of the new document manager application supports), I have to do the function that sends it with a multipart form , since I have 3 inputs (one content and two texts). Postman call:

The texts are JSON.
The steps followed are for when you only send a content type, I have tried to recreate it to send the 3 keys but it returns a 500 error.
    public  void uploadFile2(Blob file_body, String file_name){
      // Repost of code  with fix for file corruption issue
      // Orignal code postings and explanations
      // http://enreeco.blogspot.in/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html
      // http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/post-multipart-without-base64-encoding-the-body
      // Additional changes commented GW: that fix issue with occasional corruption of files

      // GW: Do not prepend footer with \r\n, you'll see why in a moment
      // String footer = '\r\n--'+boundary+'--'; 
       String ALF_ticket = ALF_getTicket();
       String BaseURL = 'https://pre-alhacena.icex.es/alfresco/s/icex';
       String reqEndPoint = BaseURL + '/records/new/files?alf_ticket=' + ALF_ticket;
        
      String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';
      String header = '--'+boundary+'\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'+file_name+'";\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';
        // Define the JSON data for data and dataExp
        String data = '{"tipoDocumento":"D023","subTipoDoc":"","titulo":"Programa (1)","nombre":"Programa (1).pdf","autor":"CRM_Integracion","fechaRegistroAplicativo":"2024-06-12T11:22:50","idioma":"I40","objSalesForce":"OS33","nombreDescripcion":"ES-01461","anoCamp":"","origenENI":"","estadoElaboracion":"","identificadorDocOrigen":"","nombreFormato":"","tipoDocumental":"","tipoFirma":"","valorCSV":"","defGeneracionCSV":"","codPoliticaAcceso":"","clasificacionENS":"","nivelConfidencialidad":""}';
        String dataExp = '{"origen":"O3","service":"O3S5","anoExp":"9876","convocatoria":"","proceso":"","fechaApertura":"2024-06-12T11:22:50","interesado":"","identificadorExterno":"ICEX_CLI_0015800000yyvc3AAA"}';
        String headerData = '--' + boundary + '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="data";\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' + data + '\r\n';
        String headerDataExp = '--' + boundary + '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dataExp";\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' + dataExp + '\r\n';
      String footer = '--'+boundary+'--';             
      String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
      while(headerEncoded.endsWith('='))
      {
       header+=' ';
       headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
      }
       String headerDataEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(headerData+'\r\n\r\n'));
      while(headerDataEncoded.endsWith('='))
      {
       headerData+=' ';
       headerDataEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(headerData+'\r\n\r\n'));
      }
               String headerDataExpEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(headerData+'\r\n\r\n'));

              while(headerDataExpEncoded.endsWith('='))
      {
       headerDataExp+=' ';
       headerDataExpEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(headerDataExp+'\r\n\r\n'));
      }
      String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file_body);
      // GW: Do not encode footer yet
      // String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
 
      Blob bodyBlob = null;
      String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());
 
      // GW: Replacing this entire section
      /*
      if(last4Bytes.endsWith('='))
      {
           Blob decoded4Bytes = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(last4Bytes);
           HttpRequest tmp = new HttpRequest();
           tmp.setBodyAsBlob(decoded4Bytes);
           String last4BytesFooter = tmp.getBody()+footer;   
           bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4)+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(last4BytesFooter)));
      }
      else
      {
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
      }
      */
     // GW: replacement section to get rid of padding without corrupting data
     if(last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
        // The '==' sequence indicates that the last group contained only one 8 bit byte
        // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
        // 8 digit binary representation of LF is 00001010
        // Stitch them together and then from the right split them into 6 bit chunks
        // 0000110100001010 becomes 0000 110100 001010
        // Note the first 4 bits 0000 are identical to the padding used to encode the
        // second original 6 bit chunk, this is handy it means we can hard code the response in
        // The decimal values of 110100 001010 are 52 10
        // The base64 mapping values of 52 10 are 0 K
        // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 for base64 mapping table
        // Therefore, we replace == with 0K
        // Note: if using \n\n instead of \r\n replace == with 'oK'
        last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
        // We have appended the \r\n to the Blob, so leave footer as it is.
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerDataEncoded+headerDataExpEncoded+headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
      } else if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
        // '=' indicates that encoded data already contained two out of 3x 8 bit bytes
        // We replace final 8 bit byte with a CR e.g. \r
        // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
        // Ignore the first 2 bits of 00 001101 they have already been used up as padding
        // for the existing data.
        // The Decimal value of 001101 is 13
        // The base64 value of 13 is N
        // Therefore, we replace = with N
        // Note: if using \n instead of \r replace = with 'K'
        last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
        // We have appended the CR e.g. \r, still need to prepend the line feed to the footer
        footer = '\n' + footer;
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerDataEncoded+headerDataExpEncoded+headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
      } else {
        // Prepend the CR LF to the footer
        footer = '\r\n' + footer;
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerDataEncoded+headerDataExpEncoded+headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
      }
        system.debug('bodyBlob');
        system.debug(bodyBlob);
    
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
      req.setMethod('POST');
      req.setEndpoint(reqEndPoint);
      req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
      req.setTimeout(120000);
 
      Http http = new Http();
      HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
}   

Can someone help me see if I'm doing something wrong on the call? Thanks in adavance!

Appears to be a duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/423577/postman-form-data-in-apex

Sadly it looks as though Salesforce doesn't support mutlipart/form-data through Apex Rest methods as detailed here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm

Note:
Apex REST currently doesn't support requests of Content-Type multipart/form-data.

