POSTMAN form-data in APEX
I have a problem, I have a call in postman to add a document in base64 with some information that works fine:

data and dataExp are a series of metadata to classify the document and in content64 is the file encoded in base64. As you can see, the call gives a 200 and I can see the document perfectly (and download it).

When I try to replicate this call in Salesforce.
        string base64String = 'JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhlcy1FUykgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDE3IDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4vTWV0YWRhdGEgMzQgMCBSL1ZpZXdlclByZWZlcmVuY2VzIDM1IDAgUj4';
         String ALF_ticket = ALF_getTicket();
         String ALF_ExpExistente;
        //= ALF_CheckExp(recordId);
         string BaseURL;
            string Endpoint;
        if (ALF_ExpExistente == null) {
            //Endpoint para crear un documento y un expediente 
            BaseURL = 'https://pre-alhacena.icex.es/alfresco/s/icex';
            Endpoint = BaseURL + '/records/new/files?alf_ticket=' + ALF_ticket;
            
            // Llamada para añadir el documento
        } else {
            // Endpoint para crear un documento
            BaseURL = 'https://pre-alhacena.icex.es/alfresco/s/icex';
            Endpoint = BaseURL + '/records/' + ALF_ExpExistente + '/files?alf_ticket=' + ALF_ticket; 
            
        }
        
        // Crear una solicitud HTTP
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(Endpoint); // Reemplazar con tu endpoint
        req.setMethod('POST');
        
        // Definir el límite del multipart/form-data
        String boundary = '----------------------------' + DateTime.now().getTime();
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);

        // Construir el cuerpo del multipart/form-data
        String body = '';
        body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dataExp"\r\n\r\n';
        body += '{"origen":"O3","service":"O3S3","anoExp":"2024","convocatoria":"","proceso":"","fechaApertura":"2024-07-02T11:53:10","interesado":"23566529Q","identificadorExterno":"ICEX_PER-BECA_a0nPv000000SwmPIAS"}\r\n';
        
        body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"\r\n\r\n';
        body += '{"tipoDocumento":"D020","subTipoDoc":"","titulo":"ES_O00016057_2024_DGIE030255","nombre":"ES_O00016057_2024_DGIE030255.pdf","autor":"CRM_Integracion","fechaRegistroAplicativo":"2024-07-02T11:53:10","idioma":"I40","objSalesForce":"OS20","nombreDescripcion":"NO TOCAR  Prueba TEst Uno","anoCamp":"","origenENI":"OR2","estadoElaboracion":"EE05","identificadorDocOrigen":"","nombreFormato":"NF34","tipoDocumental":"TD99","tipoFirma":"TF02","valorCSV":"","defGeneracionCSV":"","codPoliticaAcceso":"","clasificacionENS":"","nivelConfidencialidad":"","tipoAcceso":""}\r\n';
        
        body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.pdf"\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n';
        body += base64String +'\r\n'; // Añadir el contenido del archivo como una cadena Base64
        body += '\r\n--' + boundary + '--';

        // Establecer el cuerpo de la solicitud
        req.setBody(body);

        // Enviar la solicitud y manejar la respuesta
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        // Manejar la respuesta
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('Solicitud exitosa: ' + res.getBody());
        } else {
            System.debug('Error en la solicitud: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
        }
        
    }

note: I have forced everything so that the endpoint is the one I use in postman, also the 3 parameters (data, dataExp and content64)
The document is created but it doesn't let me download it, it's like the base64 is sent wrong. Do you know if I am replicating the call correctly?

Thanks in advance.

This question is similar to: How can I compose a multipart/form-data request?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@identigral This is kind of the opposite of that. They want to send the file data over the wire as base64, rather than as binary data. Though, on the other hand, sending data as base64 is apparently deprecated in many implementations.

@sfdcfox The Postman screenshot with form-data disagrees with you

@identigral There are options in Postman not present in the screenshot that may be affecting the payload, such as a hidden Content-Transfer-Encoding header, or maybe even automatic binary conversion. Unfortunately, we can only make an educated guess on the matter at hand. What I do know is that this is the exact behavior I'd expect (in Apex) just throwing a base64 encoded file at a server that follows the HTTP specifications.

In RFC 2388, published in August 1998, it was noted that an additional header was needed to transfer the data in non-binary formats, such as quoted-printable or base64. This is the Content-Transfer-Encoding header. RFC 7578, published in July 2015, made this header deprecated, meaning that the preferred method was to just send the binary data as is.
If your service still supports this header, you can add a line of code to fix the problem:
body += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n';
body += 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n';

However, that should be considered a short-term fix. The proper solution is to use either base64- or hex-based string conversions, which are outlined in several answers, including this one.
